# Which argument style should I use when defining function?

Tags: python

If I have a function that potentially takes a number of arguments with default values. One way to define it is this:

```
def my_func(arg1, arg2=v2, arg3=v3, arg4=v4, arg5=v5)
```

Is this equvalent to this form:

```
def my_func(arg1, **kwargs)
```

Are these two forms almost the same? I am used to the first form and the benefit of that is users can see what arguments are expected by the argument names explicitly defined in the function. The 2nd one can support any number of arguments, but users cannot clearly see what arguments are expected.  Is my understanding true? How to choose between the two?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific, known set of arguments, use the explicitly named arguments. `**kwargs` is for cases where you *can't* know all the arguments (e.g. `dict` constructor) or don't care about all of them (e.g. you're a subclass method that takes a few arguments, and passes the rest on to the superclass method, but don't want to bake the arguments of the superclass into your API). Aside from those cases, prefer naming your arguments explicitly; it lets Python check that you've received only the arguments you expect, and gives them useful names instead of accessing everything through a uselessly named `kwargs`.